# Can't require local CoffeeScript modules

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

I'm running Node.js 0.10.21. I tried both CoffeeScript 1.6.3 and master both with and without `require('coffee-script/extensions')`. Compiling the two files to JavaScript and running them directly in Node works just fine of course.

```
# ./folder/a.coffee
require('../b').test()

# ./b.coffee
exports.test = -> console.log 'yay'

# $ coffee folder/a.coffee
#
# Error: Cannot find module '../b'
#   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
#   at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
#   at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
#   at require (module.js:380:17)
#   at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/test/folder/a.coffee:1:1)
#   at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
```

Comment: Tried Node.js 0.8.26 as well. Same result.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found this SO question while trying to solve this problem for CoffeeScript **version 1.7.1**. It doesn't apply to the OP's version 1.6.3 but it may help others with this problem in 2014 and later.

The solution is to either:

```
 var foo = require('coffee-script/register');
 foo.register();
```

or, you can simply do this (which is my usual preference):

```
 require('coffee-script/register');
```

What's happening is that for CoffeeScript 1.7, [a breaking change was introduced](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/pull/3279).

It solves for cases where a variety of coffee-script versions are used within the set of dependencies that you may be loading or that your dependencies are loading.

The idea is that any particular module (or sub-module) should be able to be compiled by the version of coffee-script that it is compatible with.

Read about that here: https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/pull/3279.

Answer (score 1):

Being recreated on my computer the `coffee folder/a.coffee` works perfectly fine.

I think that adding './' at the beginning of the require in the file a.coffee may help:

```
require('./../b').test()
```

You may also try to require the files by the absolute paths, just to check that they are accessible.

Comment: Nope, the `./` doesn't help. I take it you're using CoffeeScript 1.6.3? Do you mind sharing which version of Node you used?

Answer (score 0):

`brew reinstall node` did the trick. Not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to reinstall node. Just add coffee-script as a dependency

```
npm install --save-dev coffee-script
node -v # v0.10.31
```

Answer (score 0):

Watch out for the paths, they're relative to the script you're running, not your current folder.
So if you run

```
coffee folder/a.coffee
```

and your module is in folder, you need to require `./b.coffee` not `./folder/b.coffee`